# Complete a sequence using its distances

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer

Given \$A = (a_1,\dots,a_k)\ k\ge2 \$ a sequence of positive integers, in which all elements are different.

Starting from \$i=2\$, while \$a_i\in A:\$ <sub>*(until the last element)*</sub>

- If \$d=|a_i-a_{i-1}|\$ is not already in \$A\$, append \$d\$ to \$A\$
- Increase \$i\$

**Output** the completed sequence.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Example

```
In:  16 21 11 2

     16 21 11 2 5
      --^
     16 21 11 2 5 10
         --^
     16 21 11 2 5 10 9
            --^
     16 21 11 2 5 10 9 3
              --^
     16 21 11 2 5 10 9 3
                --^
     16 21 11 2 5 10 9 3 1
                   --^
     16 21 11 2 5 10 9 3 1 6
                     --^
     16 21 11 2 5 10 9 3 1 6
                       --^
     16 21 11 2 5 10 9 3 1 6
                         --^
Out: 16 21 11 2 5 10 9 3 1 6
```

Comment: You should explain stopping and simply not appending more clearly then. For me it reads to stop doing anything.

Comment: @Noodle 9 The _if condition_ is inside a _while loop_ that continues until the index reaches the last element in \$A\$. I can't say _while \$i\le k\$_ because \$A\$ will probably get extended with new element, so the condition has to be _while \$a_i \in A\$_

Comment: Yeah, sure I see that now. But questions are always better when they're totally clear.

Comment: @Noodle 9 I left the post in the sandbox for a few days, and I though it was fine

Comment: I couple of weeks is recommended so all these warts can be sorted out.

Comment: @DomenicoModica Your new wording, "without repetition", can still be interpreted as "without _contiguous_ elements being equal". If you mean "_all_ elements are different", write it like that, or with a similar unambiguous phrase

Comment: @Luis Mendo Oh, right, I used the definition found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_permutation#cite_note-2)

Comment: @DomenicoModica Maybe it's just me. But I think it's clearer now

Comment: @LuisMendo If you don't mind, take a look at the [related challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18995/94346) in the Sandbox

Comment: @DomenicoModica Sure. I added some comments. I'm not sure if I understood the problem correclty; please disregard any comment that doesn't apply

Comment: Can we display a meaningless value at the start? (see my answer) I think it would be valid in term of "outputting the completed sequence"..

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
Δ¥Ä«Ù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JRDSw@3HFp9eOb//9GGZjoKRoY6CoZAbBQLAA)

```
Δ         until the output doesn't change:
 ¥Ä           absolute differences
   «          concatenate to the original input
    Ù         only keep unique values
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I was about to post an answer.. Only difference is that I had `üα` instead of `¥Ä`. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Apparently this wasn't optimal, since all differences are computed in every iteration, we can just concatenate with the original input.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't have thought of that, but you're indeed correct. Nice golf!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
l=input()
d=0
for i in l:l+={abs(d-i)}-set(l);d=i
print l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8c2M6@gtERDkyvF1oArLb9IIVMhM08hxypH27Y6MalYI0U3U7NWtzi1RCNH0zrFNpOroCgzr0Qh5///aEMzHQUjQx0FQyA2igUA)

Comment: 48 bytes in Python 3 by mutating the input: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoMwEADAe16xx10bwaTQgyUvEQ@RJHRhicHGQhHfHj0MTPnXz5qfrYWYIKHo4AYaFaR1AwbOIKM83OGXL4ae6eyPTs53cNy8iz8vyLnsFYlUQk@qbJzrnTaZlwZrNJibnS8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```ruby
->a,i=0{a|=[(p(a[i])-a[i+=1]).abs];redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ9PWoDqxxjZao0AjMTozVlMXSGrbGsZq6iUmFcdaF6Wm5Nf@T4uONjTTMTLUMTTUMYqN/Q8A)

Takes an array `a` as input and adds unique new elements to it using the set append operator `|=`. Terminates by throwing a rescuable TypeError (which is [now allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24552/92901)) when attempting to subtract beyond the last element of the array. By that point all of the required output has already been printed to STDOUT.

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```ruby
->a,i=0{a|=[(p(A).-a[i+=1]||0).abs]while A=a[i]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ9PWoDqxxjZao0DDUVNPNzE6U9vWMLamxkBTLzGpOLY8IzMnVcHRFigeW/s/LTra0EzHyFDH0FDHKDb2PwA)

This version avoids the TypeError at a cost of 8 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>17</s></sup> 16 bytes

```
(~.@,2|@-/\])^:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Ner0HHSMahx09WNiNeOs4v9r/k9TMDRTMDJUMDRUMAIA)

#### How it works

```
(~.@,2|@-/\])^:_
(           )^:_   until output does not change
     2   /\]       for each neighboring pair
      |@-          get the absolute difference
    ,              append the result to the list 
 ~.@               and remove duplicates
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>68</s> 57 bytes

```r
v=scan();while(any(F-(F=v)))v=unique(c(v,abs(diff(v))));v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8y2ODkxT0PTujwjMydVIzGvUsNNV8PNtkxTU7PMtjQvs7A0VSNZo0wnMalYIyUzLU0DJKNpXfbf0IzLyJDL0JDLiOs/AA)

*Edit: -9 bytes thanks to Giuseppe, and -2 more from `(F-(F=v))` (had to be tested to see whether that would work...)*

Boringly follows the instructions in the question, in the same order...

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYxBDoAgDAS/0yY1sR688RZBsAkXjCINvh7h5GZvs7N3cyFsIYpk08RISf6JZwKlama0USy49IJOFUmgpHiVA3zHbs8wNFDsIR39v/qEV1qYmGlBbB8) keeping your recursive function or [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYxLCoAgFACv8x7YQhdtxK3XCPNDQhhlvojw7GarZj0zRzPOTS6GkFULJdkzbgkIn2uJqweTbqBBIz5akSRVUtyLBwvEzJzh67rcqZLqv@oCH5ngjHMmENsL) with a `while` loop. I think taking input from `scan()` while using a `while` loop would also save bytes.

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe!  ...and I even managed to squeeze-out 2 more...

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{⍵,⍵~⍨|2-/⍵}⍣≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR71YdIK571LuixkhXH8isfdS7@FHnwv9pCo/aJig86u171NX8qHfNo94th9YbP2qb@KhvanCQM5AM8fAMBqoyNFMwMlQwNFQwAgA)

Same method as the J answer; I came up with this on my own :) also ended up being 3 bytes shorter, at least atm.

Comment: f 2 3 4 5 return 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 0 0

Comment: You can fix ^ and shorten the code by replacing `⍵,⍵~⍨` (set difference then concat) with `∪⍵,` (concat then unique). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRx6pHvVt1aox09YF07aPexY86F/5PU3jUNkHhUW/fo67mR71rHvVuObTe@FHbxEd9U4ODnIFkiIdnMFCVoZmCkaGCoaGCEVeagpGCsYKJgikA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -pl, 58 bytes

```perl
$d=abs$a[$;]-$a[++$;],/\b$d\b/||s/$/ $d/ while(@a=split)>$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBDkAwEADAr@xhD4RaK@EixAe8AIc2lWjS0KjExdstp5mwnr4WQdtpE1FP2C7qJ8v@5DQbtLOh54mEBGgJ7s35NRl0F4N3V9qjCDdQMTBD9R7hcsceRY11UXIpKvgP)

Ungolfed:

```perl
# with -pl the special var $_ is initialized with the input line string
while(
       @a = split    # array @a = the numbers currently in the $_ special var
   and $i++ < @a     # and the $i index (counter) is less than the length of @a
                     # in the golfed version $; is used instead of $i
){
  $d = abs $a[$i] - $a[$i-1] # $d = non-zero absolute diff btw element $i and $i-1
  and !/\b$d\b/              # and $d unseen before? \b is "borders" around digits
  and s/$/ $d/               # and if so append space and $d to $_
}
# with -pl the current $_ and \n is printed
```

Run:

```perl
$ echo 16 21 11 2 | perl -pl program_58_bytes.pl
16 21 11 2 5 10 9 3 1 6
```

Comment: Save two bytes by replacing `and` with `,`. One byte by removing the `!` and replacing the `&&` by a `||`. And another byte by using split instead of `/\d+/g`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxTYxqVglMVolM1YXTOkaxuroxySppMQk6dfUFOur6CuopOgrlGdk5qSqZGpr22g4JNoWF@Rklmj@/29opmBkqGBoqGD0L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhwX/dghwA)

Comment: Thanks @Abigail ! This makes Perl beat JavaScript for once :-)

Comment: Nice one! I kept playing with `-F` and `List::MoreUtils` but couldn't get a shorter solution! Another couple of minor changes can save you three more bytes: move the `++` to where you currently have `$i-1`, use `$;` instead of `$i` and reverse the condition of the while to use the implicit `;` added by `-p`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBDkAwEADAr@xhD4RaK@EixAe8AIc2lWjS0KjExdstp5mwnr4WQdtpE1FP2C7qJ8v@5DQbtLOh54mEBGgJ7s35NRl0F4N3V9qjCDdQMTBD9R7hcsceRY11UXIpKvgP "Perl 5 – Try It Online"). Also, you probably need to acknowledge that it's `` Perl 5 + `-pl` `` in the header...

Comment: Thanks to @DomHastings also. The implicit `;` feels almost too nasty, but in war and golf... :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 9 bytes

```
e⟨:ọȯ¦|⟩°
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9nYWlh//9l4p@oOuG7jcivwqZ84p@pwrD//1sxNiAyMSAxMSAyXQ)

Note that the documentation states that `ȯ` is `sign of z` when `z` is a numeric type, but it's actually `abs`...

```
e		# eval input as Gaia code (push as a list)
 ⟨	⟩°	# until there's no change:
  :		# dup the list
   ọ		# take the differences
    ȯ¦		# take the absolute values
      |		# and set union
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
;IAQƲÐL
```

-1 byte thanks to *@JonathanAllan*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/a0zHw2KbDE3z@//8fbWimY2SoY2ioYxQLAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
         # Full program taking a single list argument
     ÐL  # Repeat until the result no longer changes,
    Ʋ    # using the previous four links as monads:
 I       #  Get the forward differences of the current list
  A      #  Take their absolute values
;        #  Merge it to the current list
   Q     #  And uniquify it
         # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Either of `ÐL` or `ƬṪ` do what `ÐĿṪ` does (first one is a built-in for it, second uses the `Ƭ` alias for `ÐĿ`). I may have gone with `;ạƝQƊÐL`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah oops, I copied the wrong one apparently from the Quicks wiki page.. Not sure how that happened.. :S Thanks for the -1, I will use `ÐL`! As for `Ɲ`, is that something like apply on overlapping pairs (similar as `ü` in 05AB1E)? I can't find `Ɲ` in neither the Atoms nor Quicks wiki pages though, so I guess it's rather new?

Comment: It's on the quicks page "Apply a dyadic link or a monadic chain for all pairs of neighbouring elements".

Comment: @JonathanAllan Wth.. my Ctrl+F function just yet gave no results for sure, I even tried it twice by copying the `Ɲ` from your first comment. :/  But it's indeed there. I'm really confused about Google Chrome rn.. Ah well, thanks for the -1.

Answer (score 2):

## perl -M5.010 -a, 79 bytes

```
@F{@F}=@F;{$d=abs($F[0]-$F[1]);$F{$d}++or$F[@F]=$d;say shift@F;@F>1&&redo}say@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/BrdrBrdbWwc26WiXFNjGpWEPFLdogVhdIGsZqWqu4AYVrtbXzi4ACDm6xtiop1sWJlQrFGZlpJUBNDm52hmpqRakp@bVAYQe3//8NzRSMDBUMDRWM/uUXlGTm5xX/1/U11TMwNPivmwgA)

Reads in a line of input, with the integers space separated. Outputs the sequence with each number on a different line.

How does it work? It gets the input in the array `@F` (due to the `-a` command line argument). In the hash `%F` it stores the numbers already in `@F` (here we use the given that all numbers in sequence are positive integers<sup>†</sup>). Then, in a loop, we find the distance between the first two elements of `@F`; if not seen before, we add it to `@F` (and `%F`). We then remove the first element of `@F` and print it. We exit the loop if only one element is left, which is printed just before exiting the program.

<sup>†</sup>The sequence can never contain a zero, as that requires two subsequent elements to be the same, but that is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
Ｗ⁻Ｅθ↔⁻κ∧λ§θ⊖λθＦι⊞θκＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYo9C8IwFEV3f8UbXyAO6dClk@jiUOheOsT0SUJj0uZD@@9jKl64XDj3KC2D8tKW8tHGEmBvXI7YyxU3DpdH9DYn@tOlEjejrZPubqb9cG6kAr3IJaoP@4XDxhg8fQA0DIYc9SEurDsNwbiEVxkTVqUrZRxFy6ERHERtM03l/LZf) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⁻Ｅθ↔⁻κ∧λ§θ⊖λθ
```

Generate the absolute differences between adjacent elements of the input and filter out those appearing in the input.

```
Ｆι⊞θκ
```

While there were any new values, push them to the input and repeat.

```
Ｉθ
```

Output the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (Kona)](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 14 bytes

```
{?x,_abs-':x}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNzs9L/P8/zaravkInPjGpWFfdqqJW/3@agqGZgpGhgqGhgtF/AA)

Similar to J and APL answers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>10</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
£=âUäa
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=oz3iVeRh&input=WzE2IDIxIDExIDJd)

```
£=âUäa     :Implicit input of array U
£          :Map
 =         :Reassign to U, for the next iteration
  â        :Setwise union of U and
   Uä      :Consecutive pairs of U
     a     :  Reduced by absolute difference
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>57</s> <s>51</s> 46 bytes

<sup>*-11 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203)!*</sup>

```
#//.a_:>Keys@Counts@Join[a,Abs@Differences@a]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@19ZX18vMd7Kzju1stjBOb80r6TYwSs/My86UccxqdjBJTMtLbUoNS85tdghMVbtf0BRZl5JdFp0taGZjoKRoY6CIRAb1cbGWv8HAA) Pure function. Takes a list as input and returns another list as output. It just repeatedly appends the absolute differences to the end of the list and removes duplicates, until the list no longer changes.

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@19ZX18vMd7KziU1J7Uk1aW0IAcoU5Ja7OCVn5kXnajjmFTs4JKZlpZalJqXDBROjFX7H1CUmVcSnRZdbWimo2BkqKNgCMRGtbGx1v8B)

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates@` -> `Keys@Counts@` for 46

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
u{+GaM.:G2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v7Ra2z3RV8/K3ej//2hDMx0FI0MdBUMgNooFAA)

```
u{+GaM.:G2   
u            Apply inner function until a repeat is found, current value G, starting with input
      .:G2     Find all sublists of length 2
    aM         Absolute difference between each pair
  +G           Append to G
 {             Deduplicate
             Implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 50 bytes

```
#//.l:_[___,b_,a_,___]:>l<>d/;FreeQ[l,d=Abs[b-a]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1lfXy/HKj46Pj5eJyleJzFeB8iKtbLLsbFL0bd2K0pNDYzO0UmxdUwqjk7STYyNVfsfUJSZVxKd5qAcq1YXnJyYV1fNVW1opmNkqGNoqGNUy1X7HwA)

Takes a sequence with any head. If the sequence is already complete, returns it unchanged. Otherwise, returns the completed sequence in a `StringJoin`.

`<>` ([`StringJoin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html)) is short, flattens `List`s, does not operate on integer (non-string) arguments, and is `Flat`. It's also not `Orderless`, so can store ordered data.

```
      _[             ]                           (* match a nonatomic expression with any head, *)
    l:                                           (*  and name it l. it contains: *)
            b_,a_,                               (*   two adjacent numbers, b,a, *)
        ___,      ___                            (*   as close to the front as possible, *)
                            /;                   (* subject to the condition that *)
                              FreeQ[l,d=Abs[b-a] (*  |b-a| is not in l. *)
#//.                  :>l<>d                     (* while the condition holds, append |b-a|. *)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 45 bytes

```perl6
{|$_,{|keys abs([-] @_[++$,$++])∖@_}...^!*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/ukYlXqe6Jju1slghMalYI1o3VsEhPlpbW0VHRVs7VvNRxzSH@Fo9Pb04Ra3a/8WJlQppGtGGZjoKRoY6CoZAbBSraf0fAA)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                                         }    # Anonymous codeblock
                                    ...        # Generating a sequence
 |$_,                                          # Starting with the input
     {                             }           # Where we add to the sequence
            abs([-]            )               # The absolute difference
                    @_[++$,$++]                # Of the next pair of elements
      |keys                     ∖@_            # Set subtracting the sequence
                                    ...!*      # Continue until we run out of pairs
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 22 chars, 44 bytes

```
{⍬≡k←∪⍵∼⍨∣2-/⍵:⍵⋄∇⍵,k}
```

test:

```
  f←{⍬≡k←∪⍵∼⍨∣2-/⍵:⍵⋄∇⍵,k}
  f 16 21 11 2 
16 21 11 2 5 10 9 3 1 6 
  f 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 47 bytes

```
[ [ dup differences vabs ∪ ] to-fixed-point ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYuxDcIwFAV7pngLJJJTUMAAiIYGUUUpHPtbfJHYlv0TgRA9szAWixgFKE9357SRkMrpuD/sNrhQ8jRg1HKus2jhLGzyj2dayj9Mnk2wBBPGnr3@iphI5BYTe8F2tbpDrdEoKIUGj9KihZ0iLDtHibyhjFn3Ge/nCx0kVI6vZKsYlr8rRg8D6vIB)

### Explanation

- `[ ... ] to-fixed-point` Do `[ ... ]` to the input until it stops changing.

```
               ! { 16 21 11 2 }
dup            ! { 16 21 11 2 } { 16 21 11 2 }
differences    ! { 16 21 11 2 } { 5 -10 -9 }
vabs           ! { 16 21 11 2 } { 5 10 9 }
∪              ! { 16 21 11 2 5 10 9 }   (set union)
               ! (etc...)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 14 bytes

```
⍥(◴⊂:⌵↘1°\+.)∞
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAg4o2lKOKXtOKKgjrijLXihpgxwrBcKy4p4oieCgpmIFsxNiAyMSAxMSAyXQo=)

```
⍥(◴⊂:⌵↘1°\+.)∞
⍥(          )∞  # to fixed point
           .    # duplicate
      ↘1°\+     # differences
     ⌵          # abs
   ⊂:           # append
  ◴             # deduplicate
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 36 bytes

```
:!~&:|%(~:each_cons&2|:*&(+:-|:abs))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWN1WsFOvUrGpUNeqsUhOTM-KT8_OK1YxqrLTUNLStdGusEpOKNTUharcUKLhFRxua6SgYGeooGAKxUWwsRGrBAggNAA)

### Explanation

```ruby
:!~ & :| % (~:each_cons & 2 | :* & (+:- | :abs))
:!~ &                                             # Until fixed point...
      :| % (                                   )  #   Union of input and...
                                    +:- | :abs    #     absolute differences of...
            ~:each_cons & 2 | :* & (          )   #     consecutive pairs
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 73 bytes

```powershell
for($t=$args;$t[$i+2]){$t+=,($d=$t[$i++]-$t[$i]-replace'-')*!($d-in$t)}$t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TczBCoJAFIXh/TzFDS6p2UBjJGTMshdo0yKExK5pDI6MNwrEZ5/CCNwdfj5OZ1/k@pqMkaV15LHSg6@sC5E1Fu7eH5Av2MRJHg3IsV6HeNO/FOdyGrl01JmipEAG0WrxBbJpkaMR2Y9CnF3DJGvbMxzfHZVMtwxUCokCpSCBHagN7GELClIh0FH/NAwalljN2PzmNJErZxD@uXzYpoUAgkj4Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,i=0)=>(v=a[i]-a[++i])?f([...new Set(a).add(v>0?v:-v)],i):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDoMgEADQX2G8i3ARhw4m6Ed0JAwXweYaA00118@nDm98b1Y@t698LldbLr3vAdhKGDEsoIGjJMdxGCThukMkolp@5lkuYCTOGXQZV52dYrKCM/et1bMdhY72gjv4hzWTt8bfpoTY/w)

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 59 bytes

Port of the Python 2 answer.

```
method(x,a :=0;x foreach(i,x=x push((i-a)abs)unique;a=i);x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcexDoQgDADQX@nYJpiIww1H@JNbqkJoouAJJP17dHjDkzIifD38xhlaKjuq4fezU4jlDrwlFKNe4eo1IcrExGulnuXfg2Mv5JRGxENqQ/sxsFgD9rUQwXVLbkceDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>84</s> <s>68</s> 66 bytes

*Edit: Saved <s>16</s> 18 bytes thanks to @Neil !! This answer is now mildly competitive :P*

```
\d+
*
^
# 
{`#( _+)(_*)(\1(_*).*)
$1$2#$3 $2$4
)D` _+
^ |#

_+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsIwFAX37xQP8itJCoX3U3sCoZcobQRduHEh7vTuMa5mGOZ1fz@eV7UhrrVttxEZOwLxqSHyGFM8coqb/phygsk8WKG5zUiX2hfs/Aagi02n1rTQRYkOnSlnQU@dMwqXHw)

Not the shortest answer to this question, but it was fun to golf anyway :)

**Explanation**

```
\d+
*
```

Convert each input number to unary (using `_`'s)

```
^
#
```

Insert a `#` at the start of the input

```
{`
)`
```

Run the following 2 stages in a loop until the input stops changing:

```
#( _+)(_*)(\1(_*).*)
$1$2#$3 $2$4
```

Take the two numbers to the right of the `#` and remove the maximal number of `_`'s from each. This results in the absolute difference between the two numbers. Append this result to the end of the list.

```
D` _+
```

Deduplicate. If the number that was just added matches a number already in the list, remove it.

```
^ |#

_+
$.&
```

Once the loop breaks, remove the `#` and leading space, and convert back to decimal

Comment: I didn't think to try this in Retina, but now you've answered it, I think you can save 4 bytes by performing the subtraction as you match the two values, and more usefully I think you can save a massive 13 bytes by using a Deduplicate stage.

Comment: @Neil Wow, thanks! I might have missed something though because I ended up with 68 bytes rather than 67

Comment: I didn't have the `\b` on the Deduplicate; I don't know whether that's an error in my code. On the other hand, if that works, that makes yours 66! Your byte saving came from having the space inside `$1` - I erroneously had it outside, so my other golfs were only able to bring the score down to 67.

Comment: (Oh, and your loop only has 2 stages now.)

Comment: Looks like that works! I had misunderstood how the Deduplicate stage was working

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 90 bytes

```java
l->{for(int i=0,v;i+1<l.size();)if(!l.contains(v=Math.abs(l.get(i++)-l.get(i))))l.add(v);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU9Na8MwDL33V2g3e0nM0sMu@YCx02A99Th2cBMnVebYwVYyupLfnjlZYYwJhN7TE@@hTk4y6eqPBfvBOoIucDESanGf7f7tmtFUhNasYqWl93CQaOC6AxjGk8YKPEkKY7JYQx80diSHpn17B@laz7dTgGdr/Ngrl7@ip/zFkGqVK0tooFh0Ul4b6xgaAiwe4inDKM218PilGM84NuxOi8oaCvaeTcVB0lnIk2datIoYRhFPbpCH0kLWNZt4Ni/ZFv4nE3RgUIBRn/DknLxsask27IX0K2fpYwz7NIY09J7zH59GyKpSA7HV4rY7XjypXtiRxBD@Jm1@1Xk3L98)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>96</s> 78 bytes

```php
for($a=$argv;$n=$a[++$i];print"$n ")in_array($v=abs($n-$a[$i+1]),$a)?:$a[]=$v;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYqxCsMwDAV/JYQ32DgdlKFDHJMPKaaoQ1svilGCIV@veDnu4Oq/2rrVzu@uDpzA@msR0uUVAkqOVYucI2QYfZE3q/Ll0BJ/Dgd59A0lUPYT2G9Lz5zQopnR02YyIptv)

EDIT: 18 bytes saved with the help of Domenico Modica, thanks!

Comment: [16 bytes saved](https://tio.run/##DYqxCsMwDAV/JYQ32DgdlKFDXZMPKSYoQ1IvqlGDIV@veDnu4Oq32nupnftPHTiB9WgR0uUTAkqOVYucboQMo/dFVlbly6El3v4O8ugjSqDsJ7BfXj1zQotmRk@byYhsvgE "PHP – Try It Online") without `array_shift` and without outputting the script name :D.

Comment: @DomenicoModica Nice! Also removed the brackets, `print` doesn't need them